# Minimum and maximum entropy for source with 2^n+1 symbols

Tags: image-processing, entropy

Considering an ideal source with an alphabet with N=2^n+1 symbols, compute minimum an maximum entropy. The first symbol has the probability of 1/2.

Maximum entropy is reached when all symbols have the same probability. Because the first one has its own value for it, it remains for the rest to share equally the other half.

H(s)max=1/2+log(N-1)=1/2+n=(2n+1)/2.

Then, minimum entropy is reached when one symbol is certain to appear, and the rest are not. Again, because the 1st has already been assigned a probability, let one other to have the 1/2 probability and the rest 0.

H(s)min=1/2+1/2+0(2^n-1)=1

Am I right? It seems quite simple, but I need to be sure I understood this.

What would be the Huffman compression for the second case(minimum entropy)? I have to insert each sysmbol in the tree, don't I? Then the entropy would be huge, wouldn't it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition on the first symbol seems strange but given your interpretation, the analysis seems correct.

As for the Huffman encoding: The optimal code would use one bit per symbol (0 or 1 transmitted depending on which one of the two symbols was transmitted). No need to assign sequences to the other symbols since they are transmitted with 0 probability.

Comment: How could I compare the performances of Huffman and arithmetic coding for the case of minimum entropy? Aren't they the same?

Comment: Since in this case Huffman code has the optimal length (1 bit per symbol) this is the best you can get and arithmetic coding will give you the same results.

Answer (score 0):

If you just have two symbols with nonzero probability, you can represent them as 0 and 1. The zero-probability symbols would not be represented in a Huffman code.